# Namespaces qualified with :: in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

What does it mean if namespace in C++ is qualified with `::`? For example `::testing::Test`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`::` is the scope resolution operator.  It always means "search the global namespace for the symbol on the right."  For example:

```
namespace testing {
    int a = 1;
}

namespace foo {
    namespace testing {
        int a = 2;
    }

    int b = ::testing::a; // b has the value 1
    int c = testing::a; // c has the value 2
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It means that the `testing` namespace being referred to is the one off the global namespace, rather than another nested namespace named `testing`.

Consider the following corner case, and probably an example of bad design:

```
namespace foo
{
    struct gizmo{int n_;};
    namespace bar
    {
        namespace foo
        {
            float f_;
        };
    };

};

int main()
{
    using namespace foo::bar;

    ::foo::gizmo g;
    g.n_;
}
```

There are 2 namespaces named `foo`.  One is the top-level hanging off of the "global" namespace, and another one is nested within `foo::bar`.  then we go on to `using namespace foo::bar`, meaning any unqualified reference to `gizmo` will pick up the one in `foo::bar::foo`.  If we actually want the one in `foo` then we can use an explicit qualification to do so:

`::foo::gizmo`

Answer (score 3):

If `::` is used on the left side it means the global scope.

If you want an analogy with the filesystem, `testing::Test` would be a kind of relative path (with respect of [König lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_lookup)) whereas `::testing::Test` would be an absolute path. I hope this analogy makes it clearer and doesn't mess up your mind :-).

Comment: Argument-dependent lookup is not applied to a qualified identifier.

Answer (score 3):

I if you precede a variable name with ::, it resolves the variable to the global scope.  In this way, you can have both a local variable testing and global variable testing and differentiate between them.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int testing = 37;

int main()
{
   int testing = 42;

   cout << ::testing << ' ' << testing << endl;
}
```

Output will be 
37 42

Answer (score 0):

This invokes something called the `qualified name lookup:`

$3.4.3/1 - "The name of a class or namespace member can be referred to after the :: scope resolution operator (5.1) applied to a nested-name-specifier that nominates its class or namespace. During the lookup for a name preceding the :: scope resolution operator, object, function, and enumerator names are ignored. If the name found is not a class-name (clause 9) or namespace-name (7.3.1), the program is ill-formed."