# Is it legal C++ to declare a nested namespace `std`?

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer

The `std` namespace is special in C++, so ...

Is this legal C++?

```
// at global scope
namespace mine {
  namespace std {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'd call it insane, but is it allowed?

A reference (or non-reference) from the Standard would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems ... unwise.  `namespace mine { void foo() { using std::begin; auto it = begin(c); } }` now could behave very differently than one might expect.

Comment: @Yakk in that case, you could just use `using ::std::begin;`

Comment: I don't think there's an explicit reference in the Standard, any more than there's one that says a namespace can be named `foo`. It's permitted because nothing in the Standard prohibits it.

Comment: Sigh, spent 10 minutes trying search engines when I had actually answered [a question on this matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661912/why-does-everybody-use-unanchored-namespace-declarations-i-e-std-not-std/1662052#1662052) myself 5 years ago. I need a better memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `reserved names` standard 17.4.3.1 (and its sub-paragraphs) I can't find anything that prohibits using `std` as a nested namespace name. It's not a macro, it's not in the global namespace, and it doesn't seem to meet any of the "external linkage criteria" that would prohibit it.

It appears to be legal (although as you note extremely inadvisable).

Comment: I think this is the correct rationale: it's legal because nothing in the standard prohibits it.

Answer (score 5):

The rule in the standard that makes the `std` namespace "special" is (§17.6.4.2.1 [namespace.std]/p1):

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or
>   definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace
>   `std` unless otherwise specified.

This only applies to the top level namespace.

Comment: So, in other words, yes, it is legal C++

Comment: That says you can't add anything with the existing namespace `std`. It doesn't directly address the question of adding a namespace named `std` within another namespace -- unless you mean that the fact that it only applies to the top level namespace implies that creating `std` elsewhere is legal.